# How can I scale an image to 100% the width of the page in Safari?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to scale a large image down to the width of the user's screen. I don't want to set width: 100% because it distorts the image. Can I use CSS transforms for this?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried max-width: 100% ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, in theory, yes.  However, CSS transforms are still a [W3C working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/) at this time, and not widely supported.  The Webkit developers have started adding various `-webkit-transform` options in their nightly builds of Safari, and taking their cue, Firefox 3.5 just added some `-moz-transform` properties.  Just for fun, I just tested out `-moz-transform: scale(0.5)` on the Stack Overflow logo, and it did work in FF3.5, but the scaling algorithm used is the same as if you had forced the content to a specific width and height using HTML properties or CSS.

The best scaling is generally achieved using a cubic interpolation algorithm, such as those found in graphics programs and libraries, which is why people generally save different sizes of their images rather than scale them with HTML/CSS.  If you have a server-side language such as PHP, one option would be to fetch the master image with an HTTP request that contained the size parameters you wanted, and use a GD library (or similar) to scale the image on the fly and return it.

Answer (score 0):

[Rp.DesktopBackground Demo](http://ryanflorence.com/blog/rp-desktopbg-making-backgrounds-on-the-web-more-awesome/)

This is a mootools javascript solution I wrote to get images to look sweet.  Not sure if it's what you're going for though.